# Open contact details window per intent with phone number in android

Tags: android, android-intent

Is there a way to open the contact details window (*I mean the window/activity which is shown, if I select one, from the contacts list*) per intent with the phone number ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By using ContactsContract we open contact page

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
String.valueOf(contactID));
intent.setData(uri);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: every contact has unique id you have pass from that